# Most efficient way to extract index based values/rows in python (native, pandas, numpy)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried searching for this, but my problem is slightly more complex than a simple "this way", I think. I'm looking for ways to optimize the following problem:

I have a text file with data in N rows (hundreds of millions) and a couple of columns. The problem is that, for some reason, the column 1 has the index, while the others has the values, like so:

```
1  2.3  4.7
2  2.8  2.4
1  1.9  3.1
2  6.7  3.1
... # and so forth (first column = index, thousands of unique indexes)
```

So what I want is to read these files and concatenate them, then select all rows with each unique index, and put them in a seperate vectors for each column. The above would be:

```
# Vector 1
1  2.3  4.7
1  1.9  3.1
... # and so on
# Vector 2
2  2.8  2.4
2  6.7  3.1
... # and so on
```

I have a solution that works, but it takes a lot of time, and so I'm looking for ways to improve it, hence the title (it's an indexing problem). I'm looking for solutions using any package, but I guess pandas is a good candidate. Below is my current code (the relevant parts of it).

```
# Load data
data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path,sep=r'\t',header=None,engine='python') for f in files])
# Sort data
for col in columns:
    d_dict[name][col] = [data[col][data[0] == i] for i in range(min,max+1)] # range min/max is the min/max of possible index values in column 1
```

Both the loading of the data, and the sorting of the data takes a lot of time, but it formats the data just like I want it, and I think it also keeps the original ordering of the rows from the loaded raw data (please tell me if this assumption is wrong :p ).

I hope you have any good ideas how to speed up this process as right now it takes about 40 minutes just to do this, and that's just a sample of the amount of data I have to deal with. The final dataset is going to be approximately 10 times as big. However, I'm using barely 20% of system memory on this, so I have room to work on there (but I can dump some data if need be). I could also consider paralleling it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could argsort the first column and fancy-index the other columns with the result.

As your indices are not too large integers, we can use a trick to get the argsort in I believe O(n).

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
# mock first column
>>> idx = np.random.randint(5_000, 15_000, (50_000_000,))
>>> 
# construct sparse one-hot matrix and convert from csr to csc
# for this conversion scipy must stably argsort the column indices
# but because it can exploit certain properties of the index set
# this is faster than using argsort directly
>>> imn, imx = idx.min(), idx.max()+1
>>> rng = np.arange(idx.size + 1)
>>> spM = sparse.csr_matrix((rng[:-1], idx-imn, rng), (idx.size, imx-imn)).tocsc()
>>> 
# extract the sorting index and the group boundaries
>>> sidx, bnds = spM.indices, spM.indptr
>>>
# use them to extract the groups, here we are using the first column
# itself as an example, the result will - sanity check - be groups
# consisting of copies of the group id 
# in practice, you would use another column in place of `idx` below
>>> groups = np.split(idx[sidx], bnds[1:-1])
>>> groups
# [array([5000, 5000, 5000, ..., 5000, 5000, 5000]), array([5001, 5001, 5001, ..., 5001, 5001, 5001]), array([5002, 5002, 5002, ..., 
#
# ... VERY long list
```